# При наведении курсора на ссылку затемняется изображение и подчёркивается ссылка и наоборот

Tags: javascript, html, css

Знатоки, подскажите, как сделать, чтобы при наведении курсора на изображение — затемнялось изображение и подчёркивалась ссылка, и наоборот: при наведении на ссылку — она подчеркивалась и затемнялось изображение?

Comment: Уточните, изображение является фоном для элемента внутри которого находится ссылка или нет?

Comment: @DogeDev, о! интересная мысль :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/8h177njo/

```
div:hover p{
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 }
```

Как то так, подставишь там еще ссылку и пропишешь ей css

Comment: Перенеси код в сниппет. А вообще, я вопрос совсем по-другому понял...

Answer (score 0):

Обращаю внимание, что между всеми тремя `><` не должно быть пробелов, иначе можно будет навести мышку на пробел и затенятся оба элемента.

```css
span, a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

a {
  padding: 0 1em;
}

img:hover + a, span:hover img:not(:hover) {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<span><!--
No spaces here
--><img src=//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG><!--
No spaces here
--><a href=//ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy>Qwertiy</a><!--
No spaces here
--></span>
```